# Language mode shows "configured language" when it is not configured

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just wondered why VSCode shows that a language is configured when it is not. I want to know what causes a language to get "- Configured Language" extension as you can see in the picture.

[Picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67XPc.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Configured language` just means that this is the language of the currently active editor. You can also see the current language in the status bar:

[image]